# Acetone smoothing not working on ABSPlus-P430

Tags: abs, smoothing, vapor-smoothing, acetone

I am using a STRATASYS Fortus 250mc to 3D print some parts. I have read a lot on internet and also on some scientific literature that Acetone dissolves ABS and cold/hot vapor has been successfully used to smoothen the surfaces. But it doesn't work for me.

I followed the instructions: soaking some papers with Acetone and putting the parts in a closed container with a fan for some time. But it had no effects. Then I tried dipping the parts in Acetone and I observed that they do not react to the substance at all!

Has anybody ever had a similar experience? Maybe ABSPlus-p430 is not soluble with Acetone? in that case what is a solvent for it?

I asked the same question [here on Reddit](https://goo.gl/HNvgYH).

Comment: Where did you get your acetone? Are you sure it actually *is* acetone? I have once been sold "eco-friendly bio-acteone" which turned out to be, well, not acetone but something else entirely.

Comment: I did not buy it myself. our technician gave it to me. how can I make sure it is really Acetone or not?

Comment: I'm not sure of any tests you could do, but perhaps there's some information on the bottle? Do you have a datasheet? Supplier information?

Comment: The bottle is not the original one. I'm going to bug the technician :)

Comment: @TomvanderZanden this was apparently the problem. The material given to me seemed to be a environment friendly Acetone  used for painting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that your acetone is actually acetone. According to [the MSDS](http://usglobalimages.stratasys.com/Main/Files/SDS/P430_ABS_M30_ABS_Model/400626_0002_REV_A_EN.pdf), ABSPlus-P430 is indeed "ABS resin" so acetone smoothing should work. Some companies sell confusingly-labeled products that might be mistaken for acetone, but are actually "eco-friendly" alternatives such as 2-butoxyethanol. While these alternatives work for some of the uses for which acetone is normally used (such as cleaning or degreasing), they don't work for smoothing ABS.